# Force existing client web pages to reload - using only JSON (no eval)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

I'm a consultant working on a web app that's basically a single page app. All it does is constantly retrieve new json data behind the scenes (like once a minute), and then display it on screen.

Our clients load this app, and leave it running 24/7, for weeks on end. If errors happen when retrieving new json data, the app ignores it and keeps running.

We're rolling out an update, and want the existing clients to either become invalidated, or reload themselves without any user interaction. This feature wasn't "built in" by anyone, and we're trying to do this after the fact.

**Is there some way to make the existing clients reload without telling our end users to just reload the page?**

The following conditions define the app a bit more:

- The app uses jQuery 1.9.0
- Runs exclusively in Chrome
- Retrieves new json data frequently using jquery
- Throws away any errors it finds in json responses and uses old data.

**EDIT:**

I've had it suggested that we could try the following:

- send invalid data through the JSON responses to crash chrome (like 500 megs of data, for example)
- send window.location.reload through the JSON response (which supposedly won't work due jquery protecting against this type of thing)
- send "script" data in the JSON response and if it gets $.html(....) at some point, then it may run the script as well.

and am open to *any* suggestions on getting this to reload or kill chrome, so the client is forced to reload the page.

Comment: And what does this app do with the JSON, if it doesn't for some strange reason run the JSON through a javascript parser, you can't reload the page with JSON.

Comment: Is your question: How to reload a page?

Comment: Try pushing window.location.reload() to the client and see if it works.

Comment: Since jQuery probably filters/sanitizes its response, my last comment probably won't work. In which case, you're probably out of luck. You'd need to inject script into the page someway or have the result eval (which JSON is technically eval'd, but usually is sanitized/filtered first to avoid bad stuff like this).

Comment: It doesn't eval any json. It parses it, then uses the data in the json to set page elements using $.html() and $.text(). So the question isn't how to reload a page. It's "how to reload a page using only JSON or, I guess, possibly cookies", since both are data that's being sent to the client on each JSON request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using $.ajax to request your data, and not specifically setting your content type, then you may be able to do the following on the server:

- set the content type header to "text/javascript"
- respond with javascript, e.g. window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com"

jQuery may eval that, and simply run your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

**No it is not possible**. As far as I can tell you do not execute code from the JSON response (which is a very good thing). Thus you have no way of altering your current client's behaviour. According to your own statement:

> "Throws away any errors it finds in JSON responses and uses old data"

You will not be able to crash the user's browser by sending invalid JSON data as the errors will be suppressed.

You can build in automatic deployment in to future versions by sending an application version number and testing for changes or by using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) (which the application seems better suited to anyway as you can ensure your clients only poll the server when the JSON has actually changed).

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, create a version referance page, and make the client check this page very couple seconds, when you update the file, client will reload itself with this script.

```
var buildNo = "1.2.0.1";//

var cV = setInterval(checkVersion,(5*1000))//Every 5 sec.

function checkVersion(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"checkVersion.php?v="+buildNo,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(d){
            if(d.version != buildNo){//if version is different
                window.location.reload();
                //chrome.runtime.reload(); //for chrome extensions
            }
        }
    })
}
```

if you cant add extra page, you may just add extra variable to end of your JSON data.

Comment: This will work fine for the clients that are reloaded after our web app has been updated. But it won't work for the clients that don't reload. They won't have the new function. Moving forward, we're putting something like this in practice (good idea!). Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're `eval`uating any returned JavaScript from the server (and you probably shouldn't), I don't think of anyway of doing that without sending crap data which will cause an exception and then you roll your new way of doing things, the way @siniradam suggested

Comment: You're welcome, then there is no alternative way to do that. Sorry. If there is no responder on the client you can't force user to do that. Since this is not a socket based app and you can't push new functions.